# MPMoviePlayer or AVPlayer Frame advance

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

Is there a way to playback a video file frame by frame using either MPMoviePlayer or AVPlayer?
Or even another movie player that I do not know about?

Here is what I want to do. I want to load a video into a fullscreen player and move the content one frame at a time based on user interaction. This will need to be pretty solid as I would need to accurately control what frame the movie player was displaying at any one time.

Ideally I would love to know if it were possible to load a video and control the frame displayed using code.

I know that I could do this using a UIImageView animation but tests show that this uses FAR to much memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using AVPlayer, you can use the - (void)stepByCount:(NSInteger)stepCount method of its current AVPlayerItem to step forward or backward.

```
AVPlayer *mPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
[mPlayer.currentItem stepByCount:1];
```

Comment: @Wizfinger For me this is only working for downloaded/ Local assets not working for urls. 
Did you test with urls? 
For more detail about my question please check here-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000849/why-stepbycount-is-not-working-with-m3u8?noredirect=1#comment67300916_40000849

Comment: This doesn't work in all cases:( Even for local assets sometimes it would skip almost a 0.5 sec.

Comment: @bojan it depends on the framerate of the video. Low frame rates means bigger skips.

Comment: @Mr.Zystem it doesn't matter what the frame rate is. I had an issue with the high-frame rate (120fps). According to documentation, it depends on `The size of each step depends on the receiver’s enabled AVPlayerItemTrack objects (see tracks).` but I have no idea how. I ended up with "manual" solution that works for all frame rates. Btw. I was using "stepByCount" before, but I wasn't aware how unreliable it is until yesterday.